# How to remove or change flutter_native_splash？

Tags: flutter, dart

I use flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.2+1.
I wanted to set white background color, but I set a different color.
I called `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create` twice.
First time, with the other color. Second time with white.
So, splash pops up two times.

Has flutter_native_splash deleted or changed commands？

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seems it is caused by Springboard caching LaunchStoryboard.storyboard's images.

My problem was solved by doing this:

1. Delete your app from the device
2. Restart the device, re-install and launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try with remove and clean ;)

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove

flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```